# Why line drawn by pine script is wider than regular drawing object?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Why the line that was drawn by pine script is wider than a regular line from the drawing toolbar?

Here is how I draw a line:

```
line.new(startTime, lower_border_1, endTime, lower_border_1, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend = extend.both, width = 1, color = falseBreakoutLineColor, style=line.style_dashed)
```

[image]

Comment: What's your manually drawn line's thickness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems your line.new() call is executed on every bar - hence the line becomes 'bold' overlapping on the previous one.

Here is the snippet demonstrating the issue:

```
//@version=5
indicator("line")
// global context, executed on each bar of the chart.
line.new(time[1], 0, time, 0, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend = extend.both, width = 1, color = color.orange, style=line.style_dashed)

// local if scope, executed only if true.
if barstate.islast
    line.new(time[1], 1, time, 1, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend = extend.both, width = 1, color = color.orange, style=line.style_dashed)
```

[image]

Comment: Good catch. As a habit I drew the line on the last bar when I tried to reproduce the issue and I was looking at my chart thinking if I should go see an eye doctor because I couldn't see any difference )

Comment: I didn't check that yet, but it seems to be true. Thank you!